# WordPress + WooCommerce - disabling cart AJAX (fragments) in 3.4.0?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce has a script that runs on **every** page, upon **every** page reload, that adds 1-3 seconds to loading time. It's the "wc-ajax get_refreshed_fragments" function.

All this does is check whether the shopping cart totals have changed. Which is nice to have on the product page - but completely unnecessary on the home page or category page or any of the text-content pages.

There are manual methods (dequeue script commands to be added to functions.php) and plugins (PerfMatters, LittleBizzy's Disable Cart Fragments, etc) to remove this, which worked... *right up until the latest WooCommerce update*.

Is there a solution for disabling this script, in the latest version of WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your information is wrong:

1. PerfMatters (Brian Jackson) took their code from our GPL plugin without credit, which was originally shared by Jeff Matson [on his blog back in 2016](https://jeffmatson.net/stopping-cart-fragments-from-updating-in-woocommerce/) (credited in our readme).

```
wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart-fragments');
```

2. [Disable Cart Fragments](https://github.com/littlebizzy/disable-cart-fragments) still works fine in WC 3.4+

If it's not working on your site, most likely your theme is to blame... confirm by activating a different theme and disabling all other plugins that may be enqueuing the cart, etc.

**Update:** since so many people are now referring to this thread, I'd like to once again confirm that Kinsta (web host) is now promoting the stolen code from LittleBizzy plugins, and have contacted me to state they have nothing to do with PerfMatters. When I asked them when they'd be removing all the links and promotional material on their website for PerfMatters, they went silent...

P.S. Thanks to WP Engine and WP Rocket for crediting us! :)

Comment: @jessupi I'm wondering if [WP shutdown hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shutdown/) would work in a mu-plugin for example (if no child theme). ie. ` add_action( 'shutdown', 'shut_woocommerce_cart_fragments');
 function shut_woocommerce_cart_fragments() {
     if (is_front_page() || is_single() || is_category() || is_tag() ) wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart-fragments');
 }`

Comment: @JackLinkers Seems like a strange and unreliable approach to me. It seems a conditional enqueue would make more sense in many cases than a conditional dequeue. Personally I've usually either disabled cart fragments entirely or not at all as it depends on the stack and codebase, etc. I guess you saw that here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156558/wheres-the-best-place-to-use-register-shutdown-function

Comment: @jessupi, thanks for your feedback. I thought it would make more sense to dequeue where it wasn't needed and leave it untouched for shop related pages. No I didn't see it on [STX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156558/wheres-the-best-place-to-use-register-shutdown-function), I found [Webnots](https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-with-woocommerce-wc-ajaxget_refreshed_fragments/) article (then found about you and your autoloader as well). With some themes and plugins wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart-fragments'); doesn't work. Only way I was thinking of is using shutdown hook.

Comment: @JackLinkers It doesn't dequeue properly in some cases because so many authors are using JavaScript and AJAX etc when they don't need to be, and are not properly registering calls with WordPress when they are supposed to. My answer to dealing with bad practice authors is "avoid them" instead of trying to add more layers of janky hacky fixes on top of their janky hacky code...